# ¿ Cómo limitar la cantidad de decimales QUE PUEDO TIPEAR en un input HTML tipo number?

Tags: html, input

La consulta es sobre HTML puro (sin involucrar javascript). Lo requerido es que, al ingresar un valor en un input de type="number", tipeada una cierta cantidad de decimales, por ejemplo dos, no se pueda seguir tipeando valores. He probado con el atributo step="0.01", pero este atributo no impide seguir tipeando decimales.

Comment: Si la solución proveída ayudo a resolver tu problema, no olvides marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que buscas es algo así:

```
    <input name="my_field" pattern="^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$" />
```

Con la propiedad "pattern" indicas con una expresión regular lo que quieres que tu input acepte.

[Acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057595/allow-2-decimal-places-in-input-type-number) te dejo el enlace a una pregunta similar en el foro de ingles.